# how to count occurrences of multiple words in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I  have two tables one has a column containing words and their weightage. for example

| word | weight |
| --- | --- |
| First | 9 |
| Second | 4 |
| third | 6 |
| fourth | 7 |

and another table that has sentences. like

| Sentence | Random column |
| --- | --- |
| this is first | .. |
| Second sentence | .. |
| another first | .. |
| first and third word | .. |

now what i want to do is select words with weight 5 or more, and see how many sentence contain the keyword at-least once so the query result will be
(in the above example, I tried to handle scenarios like only one keyword is in the sentence, multiple in a single sentence, keyword not in any sentence.) Also if a keyword occurs multiple time in a sentence, the sentence should be counted once. I am trying to count sentences that contain the keyword, and not the number of keyword occurrence.

| word | count |
| --- | --- |
| First | 3 |
| third | 1 |
| fourth | 0 |

How to calculate this while keeping the query as simple as possible.(if possible)

Comment: Could your sentence have the same word more than once?

Comment: @Larnu yes, but one sentence should be counted once for one word

Comment: Then I would suggest that your statement *"and see how many times each word is used in the sentence table "* isn't accurate. if you have a sentence with the phase "I wanted to be first, I tried to be first, but I was second", the count of first would be `2` by your wording, *not* `1`.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, you are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the number of *sentences* that contain the words, you can use:

```
select w.*,
       (select count(*)
        from sentences s
        where s.sentence like concat('%', w.word, '%')
       ) as cnt
from words w
where weightage > 5;
```

This makes some assumptions on what you really mean.

- "how many times each word is used in the sentence table" means "how many sentences contain the word at least once".
- "used" can be handled by looking for the word anywhere in the sentence, regardless of surrounding characters.